# Check if the fetched array is empty or not PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if the mysql_fetch_array() function returns an empty array or not. But my code doesn't seem to work. Here I want to ensure that if the array is empty I want to display under construction message.

Code :

```
$queryContents= queryMembers();
$exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);
while($fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery)) {
   if(count($fetchSet) == 0) {
     echo "This Page is Under Construction";
   }else{
     // something else to display the content
   }
}
```

How do I check to acheive such feature ?

Comment: What *is* in $fetchSet? (try a var_dump() and inspect)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use mysql_num_rows to count number of rows. try this.

```
$exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);

if(mysql_num_rows($exeQuery)== 0){
   echo "This Page is Under Construction";
}
else{
   while($fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery)) {

     // something else to display the content

   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You really should be using `mysql_num_rows` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

However, on a side note, you should use php `empty()` instead. https://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 4):

> When you use mysql_fetch_array(), it returns the rows from the data
>   set one by one as you use the while loop.

*If there will be no record, while loop wont execute. In this case, declare a boolean variable and make it true if it enters the while loop. Like:*

> ```
> $queryContents= queryMembers();
> $exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);
> $recordExists = 0;
> while($fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery)) {
>      if($recordExists == 0 )
>        $recordExists = 1;
>      // something else to display the content
>
> }
>
> if($recordExists == 0 ){
>     echo "This Page is Under Construction";
> }
> ```

*Hope this works!*

Comment: what is the point of running the loop if there are no results?

Comment: You are absolutely right. This was just another implementation. However, yours good! or to be specific, your;s right!

Comment: I am not trying to say my answers is the only way of doing this. here if the number of rows are 0 there is no need of going to a while loop. so it is more efficient to have inside else part.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
while($r[]=mysql_fetch_array($sql));
// now $r has all the results
if(empty($r)){
  // do something
}
```

source: [php doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#105221)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(empty($fetchSet) 
{
   echo "This Page is Under Construction";
}
else
{
 // something else to display the content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the while loop never runs if there are no results. mysql_fetch_array returns null/false if there are no more results. What you need yo do is check with mysql_num_rows first, before the while.

```
$queryContents= queryMembers();
$exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);

 if(mysql_num_rows ($exeQuery) == 0) {
     echo "This Page is Under Construction";
 }

while($fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery)) {
    // something else to display the content
}
```

Comment: what is the point of running the loop if there are no results?